# Spatial adjustment using control points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, spatial-adjustment

I want to spatial adjust a bunch of points using control points. I have two layers. One is the layer I want to move with the control points in it, and another is the layer with target points pairing with the control points. My QGIS version is 3.22.4. I have already tried vector bender, but it moved the points to a strange location. Is there any way to spatial adjust points with QGIS?

The first image is the points I want to move. green points are the control points. The second image is the target points paring with the control points with the same number.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide example data, or at least a screenshot? Why do the points need adjustment instead of being digitized correctly in the first place?

Comment: Do the points share a common attribute with the GCPs? Is the adjustment uniform for all points or is variable?

Comment: @Erik I've add some screenshots. Because the location is measured by a 20m*20m grid instead of GPS.

Comment: @Matt No, the points don't share common attribute with the GCPs. The adjustment is uniform for all points.

Comment: You want to move all the blue points to the green?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a QGIS Graphical Model to perform order 1 polynomial transformations to vector layers.

Order 1 polynomial is an [affine (linear) transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

The advantage of this model over [Vector Bender plugin](https://github.com/olivierdalang/VectorBender), is that the transformation will allways be order 1 polynomial, regardless of the number of control points chosen. A minimum of three pairs of points are required, and a least-squared algorithm is used for more than three.

For this model to work, you must create a lines layer called *'gcps'*, with the same CRS of the points layer to be adjusted.

Draw one line for each control point, in the direction of the transformation. Then, run the 'Order 1 transformer by GCPs' process. INPUT parameter is the layer to be adjusted.

[image: 1]

To get the model in your toolbox, save the following text in a 'order_1.model3' file and import it with the Add Model to Toolbox option.

```html
<!DOCTYPE model>
<Option type="Map">
  <Option type="Map" name="children">
    <Option type="Map" name="gdal:convertformat_1">
      <Option type="bool" name="active" value="true"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="alg_id" value="gdal:convertformat"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="color" value=""/>
      <Option type="Map" name="comment">
        <Option type="QString" name="color" value=""/>
        <Option type="QString" name="component_description" value="Performs the order 1 polynomial transformation using start and end points of geometries stored in a called 'lines' layer."/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_height" value="60"/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_pos_x" value="440"/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_pos_y" value="150"/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_width" value="100"/>
        <Option type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed" value="true"/>
        <Option type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option type="QString" name="component_description" value="Transform"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_height" value="30"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_pos_x" value="300"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_pos_y" value="165"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_width" value="180"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="id" value="gdal:convertformat_1"/>
      <Option type="Map" name="outputs">
        <Option type="Map" name="Transformed">
          <Option type="QString" name="child_id" value="gdal:convertformat_1"/>
          <Option type="QString" name="color" value=""/>
          <Option type="Map" name="comment">
            <Option type="QString" name="color" value=""/>
            <Option type="QString" name="component_description" value=""/>
            <Option type="double" name="component_height" value="60"/>
            <Option type="double" name="component_pos_x" value="0"/>
            <Option type="double" name="component_pos_y" value="0"/>
            <Option type="double" name="component_width" value="100"/>
            <Option type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed" value="true"/>
            <Option type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed" value="true"/>
          </Option>
          <Option type="QString" name="component_description" value="Transformed"/>
          <Option type="double" name="component_height" value="30"/>
          <Option type="double" name="component_pos_x" value="490"/>
          <Option type="double" name="component_pos_y" value="255"/>
          <Option type="double" name="component_width" value="200"/>
          <Option type="invalid" name="default_value"/>
          <Option type="bool" name="mandatory" value="false"/>
          <Option type="QString" name="name" value="Transformed"/>
          <Option type="QString" name="output_name" value="OUTPUT"/>
          <Option type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed" value="true"/>
          <Option type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed" value="true"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
      <Option type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed" value="true"/>
      <Option type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed" value="true"/>
      <Option type="Map" name="params">
        <Option type="List" name="INPUT">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" name="parameter_name" value="INPUT"/>
            <Option type="int" name="source" value="0"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="OPTIONS">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option type="QString" name="expression" value="'-order 1 ' ||&#xa;aggregate( &#xa;  layer:= 'gcps', &#xa;  aggregate:= 'concatenate',&#xa;  expression:=&#xa;    '-gcp ' || &#xa;&#x9;x( start_point( $geometry)) || &#xa;&#x9;' ' || &#xa;&#x9;y( start_point( $geometry)) ||&#xa;&#x9;' ' ||&#xa;&#x9;x( end_point( $geometry)) ||&#xa;&#x9;' ' ||&#xa;&#x9;y( end_point( $geometry)),&#xa;  concatenator:= ' ')"/>
            <Option type="int" name="source" value="3"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option type="Map" name="designerParameterValues">
    <Option type="QString" name="INPUT" value="desde_ab5b642a_617c_43e3_b534_07d0f9784913"/>
    <Option type="QString" name="LINES" value="lineas_9451fedc_4089_4e76_849c_12e9da74e703"/>
    <Option type="bool" name="VERBOSE_LOG" value="true"/>
    <Option type="QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition" name="gdal:convertformat_1:output">
      <Option type="Map">
        <Option type="Map" name="create_options">
          <Option type="QString" name="fileEncoding" value="System"/>
        </Option>
        <Option type="Map" name="sink">
          <Option type="bool" name="active" value="true"/>
          <Option type="int" name="type" value="1"/>
          <Option type="QString" name="val" value="TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="groupBoxes"/>
  <Option type="Map" name="help">
    <Option type="QString" name="ALG_CREATOR" value="Gabriel De Luca"/>
    <Option type="QString" name="ALG_DESC" value="Performs the order 1 polynomial transformation using start and end points of line geometries stored in a (must be called 'gcps') layer."/>
    <Option type="QString" name="ALG_HELP_CREATOR" value=""/>
    <Option type="QString" name="ALG_VERSION" value="1"/>
    <Option type="QString" name="INPUT" value="Vector layer to be transformed."/>
    <Option type="QString" name="SHORT_DESCRIPTION" value=""/>
    <Option type="QString" name="gdal:convertformat_1:Transformed" value=""/>
  </Option>
  <Option name="modelVariables"/>
  <Option type="QString" name="model_group" value=""/>
  <Option type="QString" name="model_name" value="Order 1 transformer by GCPs"/>
  <Option type="Map" name="parameterDefinitions">
    <Option type="Map" name="INPUT">
      <Option type="List" name="data_types">
        <Option type="int" value="-1"/>
      </Option>
      <Option type="invalid" name="default"/>
      <Option type="invalid" name="defaultGui"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="description" value="INPUT"/>
      <Option type="int" name="flags" value="0"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="help" value=""/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="name" value="INPUT"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="parameter_type" value="vector"/>
    </Option>
    <Option type="Map" name="gdal:convertformat_1:Transformed">
      <Option type="bool" name="create_by_default" value="true"/>
      <Option type="int" name="data_type" value="-1"/>
      <Option type="invalid" name="default"/>
      <Option type="invalid" name="defaultGui"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="description" value="Transformed"/>
      <Option type="int" name="flags" value="0"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="help" value=""/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="name" value="gdal:convertformat_1:Transformed"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="parameter_type" value="vectorDestination"/>
      <Option type="bool" name="supports_non_file_outputs" value="false"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="parameterOrder"/>
  <Option type="Map" name="parameters">
    <Option type="Map" name="INPUT">
      <Option type="QString" name="color" value=""/>
      <Option type="Map" name="comment">
        <Option type="QString" name="color" value=""/>
        <Option type="QString" name="component_description" value="Vector layer to be transformed."/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_height" value="60"/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_pos_x" value="75"/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_pos_y" value="60"/>
        <Option type="double" name="component_width" value="90"/>
        <Option type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed" value="true"/>
        <Option type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed" value="true"/>
      </Option>
      <Option type="QString" name="component_description" value="INPUT"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_height" value="30"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_pos_x" value="210"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_pos_y" value="75"/>
      <Option type="double" name="component_width" value="180"/>
      <Option type="QString" name="name" value="INPUT"/>
      <Option type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed" value="true"/>
      <Option type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed" value="true"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
</Option>
```

Under the hood, it runs an [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) command.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was solved.